# How can I convert char to int without returning some ascii character in C#?

Tags: c#, type-conversion

```
char c = '0';
int number = (int) c;
Debug.Log(number);
```

And it will return an invisible character while I actually want to cast '0' to 0 as in integer. What I already tried :

- Methods of Convert class
- GetNumericValue method
- And this : (int) c - '0'

Comment: Why didn't [`GetNumericValue()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7k33ktz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) work?  it should.

Answer (score 4):

Subtracting by `0` does work, for `0-9`.

```
char c = '0';
int number = (int)c - '0';
```

This won't work as intended for [other numerals](http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html).

Comment: No, unfortunately not for me.

Comment: @Nik the only thing I can guess is that your character is not in the range `0` (U+0030) to `9` (U+0039).

Answer (score 2):

Try [int.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
char c = '0';
int number = int.Parse(c.ToString());
```

Be aware that this will cause exception if the parameter is invalid.

You could also try: [int.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
char c = '0';
int number;
if (int.TryParse(c.ToString(),out number))
{
   //parse successfully
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work unfortunately. Could it because I'm using .net 2.5?

Comment: @Nik: it does not compile or has exception at runtime?

Comment: It compiles but I'm still getting weird characters.

Comment: @Nik: what did you get for '0' ?

Comment: an invisible character. I added 1 then it turned into a pi character.

Comment: @Nik: what value did you get for `int number`? I'm confused when you said you got weird characters.

Answer (score 2):

you can write a simple extension method to convert `char` to `int`, additionally you can check if char can actually be converted into integer.

```
public static int ToInt32(this char c)
{
    if (!Char.IsNumber(c))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Char is not a number", "c");
    }
    return c - '0';
}
```

Usage

```
[Test]
[TestCase('1', ExpectedResult = 1)]
[TestCase('a', ExpectedException = typeof(ArgumentException))]
public int ChatToNumTest(char c)
{
    return c.ToInt32();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

GetNumericValue should have worked unless you forgot to cast it to int since it returns double:

```
char c = '0';
int number = (int)char.GetNumericValue(c);

//another way...
 int number = Convert.ToInt32(c.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a good idea to check that the `char` is in your expected range,

```
int number = -1;
char c = '0';
if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
  number = (int) c - '0';
} else {
  Debug.Log("Character " + c + " isn't a digit.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [the following](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw9t1kbk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you *only* want the value of characters that correspond to standard digits base 10:

```
var number = System.Globalization.CharUnicodeInfo.GetDecimalDigitValue(c);
```

Use [the following](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56at3k0x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you want numeric values for both digits and more general Unicode numeric characters, e.g. fractions like ½:

```
var number = System.Globalization.CharUnicodeInfo.GetNumericValue(c);
```